# corefx sources are not being rebuilt as expected

Tags: .net-core, coreclr

I am attempting to build a dotnet core application that links against a custom built corefx. I plan to make some changes to System.Collections, but for now I am just trying to get the system running properly. It appears that my edits to source files are not being incorporated into the final packages as I would expect. Also, the corefx version numbers are changing even though I am not explicitly (i.e. git pull) pulling from the repository.

I am following steps as follows (outlined in the [corefx dogfooding docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dogfooding.md#more-advanced-scenario---using-your-local-corefx-build)):

- download and install the [latest core 3.0.x SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk)
- git clone https://github.com/dotnet/corefx.git
- cd corefx
- set BuildNumberMinor=1
- build -Release
- add package path to nuget.config in my Test.sln folder

> ```
> <packageSources>
>   <clear />
>   <add key="local coreclr" value="c:\<path>\corefx\bin\packages\Release" />
> </packageSources>
> ```

- add a package reference in my Test.csproj

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
>   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
>   <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
>   <PackageConflictPreferredPackages>Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp.4.6.0-preview1-27013-1;runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp.4.6.0-preview1-27013-1;$(PackageConflictPreferredPackages)</PackageConflictPreferredPackages>
> </PropertyGroup>
> <ItemGroup>
>   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp" Version="4.6.0-preview1-27013-1" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

Two things are not going as expected:

1. I modified Dictionary.cs to throw an exception in the default constructor, but it is not being thrown in my simple test program when it instantiates a Dictionary
2. under corefx\bin\packages\Release, the package version has incremented to Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp.4.6.0-preview1-**27014**-1.nupkg, whereas yesterday it was **27013**

It seems as though the build system is downloading whatever the latest bits are and is disregarding my source.